# ImportError in opencv on manjaro linux

Tags: python, linux, opencv, manjaro

I'm using manjaro linux recently, and working on a facial recognition project using opencv, so first i downloaded the opencv packages using:

```
sudo pacman -S opencv
```

and it was installed perfectly, then i ran the code, but there's an error which i can't find a solution to it online that says:

```
import cv2
ImportError: libhdf5.so.101: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

so what can i do in this case?
I have tried downloading opencv from other resources, but i still have the same problem.
Also, if anyone can direct me to a way to implement facial recognition, that would be great, since i'm stuck for a while now.

Comment: you only installed opencv. you need python bindings for opencv (surely something like python-opencv)

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the problem using the following commands:

```
pacman -Syu base-devel opencv opencv-samples
pacman -S hdf5
```

then you need to install the gtkglext library, and you can do so by using:

```
pacman -S gtkglext
```

this should work